# ML Classification for categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, classification, catboost

I came across a problem that needed programming a ML model for classification between 2 classes. Now the problems we faced are mentioned below in points:

1. Data points for Class A were somewhere around 24,000 and Class B were around 6500. This caused high skewness towards Class A
2. Data was majorly categorical(20 categorical columns/features out of 25 features)
3. Using One-hot encoding caused the features to increase exponentially and label encoding gave us incorrect results.
4. We also used feature engineering and took the best possible features.

We used algorithms like SVM, Log-Reg, NB, KNN, Random Forest etc. but the accuracies did not  increase. Next we used Cat-Boost algorithm to train on the data and predict the classes A/B
We also used SMOTE to generate data for Class B to get upto 15,000 values and down sampled Class A data points to 15,000 to get uniformity in the data.

We also used SMOTE to generate a few data points for Class B and pump up from 6500 to 10,000 and down sampled Class A to 10,000

Even after carrying out all these steps, my Cat-Boost model gave a test accuracy of 91% and Logloss of 0.12.

Even though the numbers were promising, the model is unable to predict Class B correctly. Class A is predicted quite well with 9/10 correct predictions but Class B is as low as 2/10.

What more could I do to improve my predictions towards Class B?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you made a good job, You've already done the first things which I think.

My humble suggestions are ;

You can use another SMOTE technique which is:

- ADASYN

Also you can try improve your models with hyperparameters;

- GridSearch
- RandomSearch
- Optuna (is my favourite one!)

Comment: Thank you so much. These suggestions are really helpful. Will implement soon and get back to you in a days time. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi guys, So sorry for responding so late. I have tried hyperopt and Optuna for tuning hyperparameters and checking. Results are still the same unfortunately.